# Javascript functions initialized as a expression

Tags: javascript

Why does function expressions does not be in stack if it is invoked before its occurence?

```
console.log( myFunc());
var myFunc = function(){
};
```

Regular function declaration works right.

Comment: `var myFunc;console.log(myFunc());myFunc=function(){}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: Ask and answered dozens of times here on SO. Please search for "function hoisting".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This confusion is due to one major difference in the way that a JavaScript engine
loads data into the execution context. Function declarations are read and available in an execution context before any code is executed, whereas function expressions are not complete until the execution reaches that line of code.**

```
console.log(myFunc());
function myFunc(){
 //
}
```

This works because of **function declaration hoisting**.

Without function declaration hoisting, the top of the source tree, will be empty. Hence you get the `unexpected identifier` error for your code.

Comment: To be more precise, this has nothing to do with function expressions. Given a variable declaration with initialization, only the declaration is hoisted, not the initialization itself. This only happens when the line of the assignment is reached.

Comment: @FelixKling OP has asked, why the function that is a part of the initialization statement and not a part of function declaration is causing an error. I have given the accurate reason as to why. I really don't appreciate your unnecessary down vote.

Comment: You shouldn't jump to conclusions and think that I downvoted just because I commented.

Comment: I did think you did that. Sorry for that.